# Did Rohan also become a ghost at the end?

Tags: character, ending, vaastu-shastra

In the movie *[Vaastu Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaastu_Shastra_(film))*, every dead person became a ghost. Has Rohan also become a ghost?